# sort a numpy array (having strings, dictionaries and numbers ) with respect to specific column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have the following numpy array (having strings, dictionaries and numbers ) and would like to sort this array according to the last column (number)

```
X=[['few' {'age': 'young'} {'salary': 'low'} 0.8]
['few' {'salary': 'low'} {'age': 'young'} 0.3]
['few' {'age': 'young'} {'salary': 'medium'} 0]
...
['most' {'salary': 'medium'} {'education': 'upper'} 0.125]
['most' {'education': 'upper'} {'salary': 'high'} 0]
['most' {'salary': 'high'} {'education': 'upper'} 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one way using the last column `X[-1]` as the sorting `key`

```
import numpy as np

X=np.array([['few', {'age': 'young'}, {'salary': 'low'}, 0.8],
['few', {'salary': 'low'}, {'age': 'young'}, 0.3],
['few', {'age': 'young'}, {'salary': 'medium'}, 0],
['most', {'salary': 'high'}, {'education': 'upper'}, 1]])

X = np.array(sorted(X, key=lambda X: X[-1]) )
# array([['few', {'age': 'young'}, {'salary': 'medium'}, 0],
#        ['few', {'salary': 'low'}, {'age': 'young'}, 0.3],
#        ['few', {'age': 'young'}, {'salary': 'low'}, 0.8],
#        ['most', {'salary': 'high'}, {'education': 'upper'}, 1]],
#       dtype=object)
```

Another option could be to use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) where `-1` signifies the last entry/index

```
from operator import itemgetter

X = sorted(X, key=itemgetter(-1))
```

Comment: In your solution, I can access 0th row with X[0]  but I want to access it  X[0,:] as in original data

Comment: @diyar: You have to convert the output to numpy array to be able to perform `X[0,:]` slicing. Check my edited solution. Let me know if it works